# Make control array in code

Tags: vb6

This code does not work I want to create a control array on my Form_Load in VB6 because I have to make 225 of them for a scrabble board and they have to be precise. My code is:

```
Private lblblocks(1 To 225) As Label

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 15
    For j = 1 To 15
        Dim arrnum As Integer
        arrnum = (i - 1) * 15 + j
        Load lblblocks(arrnum)
        With lblblocks(arrnum)
            .Width = 1000
            .Height = 1000
            .Top = (i - 1) * 1000
            .Left = (j - 1) * 1000
            .Visible = True
            .BackColor = Int(Rnd(1) * 255) + &H100 * Int(Rnd(1) * 255) + &H10000 * Int(Rnd(1) * 255)
        End With
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I used the backcolor to see all my label boxes. This code does not work. I get an error "Object variable or With block variable not set". Any help? I don't know what is wrong. I would like to keep the label boxes in a control array I know how to do it without making it a control array.

Comment: At what line do you get the error?

Comment: Also, do you want a "control array" (as you say) or "array of controls" (as your code says)? They are somewhat different things.

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, you need to place the *first* `lblblocks` control on the form at design time.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Konard's comment: Should we also reply all the vb6 tagged questions as "will not solve"? :P

Comment: @anishsane No, of course not. There are huge legacy systems that still need being supported. But my comment was 100% earnest, and is the best advice I can honestly give on the subject. Oh, and I’m a long-time VB6 programmer and absolute fan of the language. Flagging and deleting my comment was absolutely inappropriate.

Comment: I’ll reinstate my original comment: if you are new to programming and starting to learn, do *not* learn VB6. The language is obsolete and superseded – learn a modern language instead. Learning VB6 nowadays would be akin to learning to write typewriter first before switching to computers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cody Gray had it correct in his comment. I don't believe you can create a control array on the fly only in code in VB6. You have to place one instance of the control on the form and give it an `Index` property value of zero. This creates a control array with only one element, at index zero. You can then modify your code to produce the desired result, like so:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To 14
        For j = 0 To 14
            Dim tileIdx As Integer
            tileIdx = i * 15 + j

            'If the tile index is zero, we already have that control,
            'so there's no need to load new instance. Otherwise, use the 
            'Load method to create a new control in the array with the 
            'specified index.
            If tileIdx > 0 Then
                Load lblTile(tileIdx)
            End If

            With lblTile(tileIdx)
                .Width = 1000
                .Height = 1000
                .Top = i * 1000
                .Left = j * 1000
                .Visible = True
                .BackColor = Int(Rnd(1) * 255) + &H100 * Int(Rnd(1) * 255) + &H10000 * Int(Rnd(1) * 255)
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

As noted in the comment, you don't need to load another instance of the control at array index zero because you did that at design time. I also iterated my array starting from zero for slightly easier calculation of the indices.

Comment: Thanks for the code/answer, but I still get the same error on the .Width line. How would I declare the array, @BobMc?

Answer (score 0):

**we can add from scratch**

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim rownum As Integer, ColNum As Integer
'Dim lblblocks(1 To 225) As Label
Dim lblblocks() As Label
Dim wwidth As Integer, hheight As Integer
wwidth = 400: hheight = 200
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
rownum = 20: ColNum = 25
ReDim lblblocks(1 To rownum * ColNum)
For i = 1 To rownum
    For j = 1 To ColNum
        Dim arrnum As Integer
        arrnum = (i - 1) * ColNum + j
        Set lblblocks(arrnum) = Me.Controls.Add("VB.Label", "LB" & arrnum)
        With lblblocks(arrnum)
         'Set Bb(i) = formname.Controls.Add("VB.CommandButton", "Bb" & i)
            .Width = wwidth
            .Height = hheight
            '.Top = (i - 1) * 100
            '.Left = (j - 1) * 400
            .Top = (i) * hheight
            .Left = (j) * wwidth
            .Caption = arrnum
            .Visible = True
            .BackColor = Int(Rnd(1) * 255) + &H100 * Int(Rnd(1) * 255) + &H10000 * Int(Rnd(1) * 255)
        End With
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```