# Generating buttons dynamically via code

Tags: button, vb6, grid

I want to generate a grid on a form in vb6 of buttons. I'm working on a reservation so I would assume generating buttons for each selection (e.g. A1, E7, etc.) would be the way to go.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to accomplish this.

I'm working on a seat reservation system. So I would want the grid to be generated from the number of seats inputted via a database (shouldn't really matter, but what the hay).

So for example if the total number of seats was 100, I would want the form to generate a 10x10 grid of buttons. When one of the buttons is clicked (each one being unique), I would be able to reserve them by modifying/adding the seat to the reserved table in a database.

Been trying to find solutions all over the place but it seems there isn't a fix answer to this in VB6.

Comment: You'll want to use a control array.  Take a look at this: http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?174949-How-to-create-a-dynamic-control-array-with-100-commandbuttons

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make control array in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048634/make-control-array-in-code)

Comment: You could get yourself in trouble with this approach. Adding that many controls to a form will likely seriously degrade the performance of your application. You can learn a little more here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229756

Answer (score 2):

See below for what you ask for:

```
'1 form with
'  1 commandbutton: name=Command1  index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click(Index As Integer)
  Caption = CStr(Index)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  For lngIndex = 1 To 100
    Load Command1(lngIndex)
  Next lngIndex
  For lngIndex = 0 To Command1.UBound
    With Command1(lngIndex)
      .Caption = CStr(lngIndex)
      .Visible = True
    End With 'With Command1(lngIndex)
  Next lngIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth / 10
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / 10
  For lngIndex = 0 To Command1.UBound
    lngRow = lngIndex \ 10
    lngCol = lngIndex Mod 10
    Command1(lngIndex).Move lngCol * sngWidth, lngRow * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Next lngIndex
End Sub
```

Be careful though as lots of control on 1 form can slow down the perfomance a lot

If the layout of the seats is a nice grid, you might be better off using a (msflex) grid control

Another option would be to load a picture of the seat-map and let the user click on the picture after which you can use the X and Y coordinates to determine which seat was clicked ... that way you can also use different colors in the picture, and get the color on which the user clicked to make a preselection of the type of seat