# How could I add events on dynamically-created array of controls?

Tags: vb6

First of all, I am using VB6, not VB.Net.

Now, I am trying to add events on dynamically-created array of controls. But when I try to add the WithEvents keyword to my array of controls, I get a "Compile Error: Expected: As" error.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents btnNumbers() as CommandButton

Private Sub Form_Load()

    ReDim btnNumbers(1 to 10) as CommandButton
    Dim i as Integer

    For i = 1 To UBound(btnNumbers) Then

        Set btnNumbers(i) = Controls.Add("VB.CommandButton", "btnNumber" & i)
        Set btnNumbers(i).Container = Form1

        With btnNumbers(i)

            'Properties of btnNumbers here...

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

I want the buttons to display a message box that says it's number. Like for example when I clicked btnNumber4, a message box that says "I am Number 4!" to appear. I know how to do this message box part. The problem is that I can't add events to these buttons in order to do this.

Seeing that WithEvents doesn't seem to work, is there another way to add events to these buttons?

Thanks.

Comment: If that suits you, [create a control array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16049866/11683).

Comment: Will try this now. This may fit to a part of my program. But I will still need to be able to add events to dynamically-created controls.I'm gonna need it for making a list of items with data taken from the database, and each of those items will have their own Frame as a container and Labels that will serve as buttons.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what control arrays are for. Put your frame with contents into a UserControl and make a control array of them on the main form. The alternative is to declare a helper class with a single WithEvents field for each control in the frame and make this class forward the events to a central handler (e.g. in a module), then create an instance of such helper class for each control.

Comment: There is also `VBControlExtender` but usually control arrays make more sense and are simpler and more efficient.