# Variable to refer to Control array?

Tags: vb6, controls

I know that it [isn't possible to generate a control array at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048634/make-control-array-in-code).

However, is it possible to have several control arrays that I sub in at different points, referred to via a variable? IE

```
dim CArray() as controls

CArray = Labels
Foo(CArray)
CArray = OtherLabels
Foo(CArray)
```

My attempts to do this so far lead to a compile-time error, as it won't allow the control array actually on the form to be referred to without using a method or element. It gives the error:

> Arugment not optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim CArray As Object
    Set CArray = Labels
    Foo CArray
End Sub

Sub Foo(CtrlArray As Object)
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 0 To CtrlArray.ubound
        CtrlArray(i).Caption = Rnd
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I feel silly for not realising that a control array was obviously an object, and not a literal array of controls now.